# Custom DropDownFor loading Entity according to value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I am working in an ASP.NET MVC project and I have a custom implementation of a DropDown list in my form.
I am selecting an account, and according to that account I want to be able to select the contacts made under the account. ( The Contacts model has an Accountid )

Here is my code below

```
 public static MvcHtmlString AccountContactsDropdownFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, Guid parentId, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        QueryRequestHelper<AccountContacts, FMRequestDispatcher> request = new QueryRequestHelper<AccountContacts, FMRequestDispatcher>();
        EntityReference reference = new EntityReference() { EntityName = "Account", Id = parentId };
        int count = 0;
        IEnumerable query = request.Query(string.Empty, string.Empty, 0, 100, out count, reference);

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Contact contacts in query)
        {
            SelectListItem li = new SelectListItem();
            li.Value = contacts.Id.ToString();
            li.Text = contacts.FirstName[0] + ". " + contacts.LastName;
            items.Add(li);
        }

        return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, items, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

And here is the code of it my form

```
                <li>
                    @Html.Label(Localization_Financial.Account) <br>
                    @Html.AccountNameDropdownFor( m => m.AccountId)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.Label(Localization_Financial.Contact) <br>
                    @Html.AccountContactsDropdownFor(m => m.ContactId, Model.AccountId)
                </li>
```

So whenever I am selecting an account in the dropdownfor above I want my application to sort of reload or do something so it updates the select box with the contacts which belong to my account.

Is there an effective way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself after a while.

This is my code to do so.

```
        myFunction();
    $("#AccountId").change(myFunction);
})

function myFunction() {
    $.getJSON("/Crm/Invoice/JsonContacts", { AccountId: $("#AccountId").val() },
        function (result) {
            var ddl = $('#ContactId');
            ddl.empty();
            var count = "0";

            $(result).each(function () {
                count = 1;
                ddl.append(
                    $('<option/>', {
                        value: this.Id
                    }).html(this.FirstName[0] + ". " +  this.LastName)
                );
            });
}
```